# Scala program error

Tags: arrays, scala, function, parameters

When I run the below scala program in cloudera quickstart  , I getting small error which I unable to rectify it. I am starter for scala programming.

```
object sort {
  def sort(s:Array[Int] => Unit ){
    var a=new Array[Int](3);
    a(0)=1;
    a(1)=1;
    a(2)=1;
    s(a);
  }

  def qsort(a:Int*){
    println("qsort printed");
  } 

  def main(args:Array[String]){
    sort(qsort);
  }
}
```

I am getting error

```
[cloudera@quickstart scalap]$ scalac sort.scala
sort.scala:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[Int] => Unit
 required: Array[Int] => Unit
sort(qsort);
     ^
one error found
```

Please show me the solution.

Comment: `sort(qsort(_:_*))` would do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Kolmar, even this resolved me :)

Comment: It's more correct to follow Daniel's answer. My comment was more of a joke about cryptic syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple, you can pass an instance of Array[Int] to a function that expects a Seq[Int], but not vice versa, as Array is more specific than Seq. To fix it, simply change tthe `qsort` definition to:

```
def qsort(a:Array[Int]){
  println("qsort printed");
}
```

or change definition of sort to receive a sequence. Either one will make the types match.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Can you some suggestion from where to start to learn scala program . which gives simple way to teach.

Comment: Sure. There are plenty of good books out there, or just learn by doing and googling. It kinda depends on if you know other languages or not. Check the coursera free online course from the very authors of scala [here](https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun).